# Why is checked="checked" not validating in js?

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am a bit baffled on this. I have this html -

```
<input type="radio" id="20577091" name="q_engine" value="20577091" style="position: absolute; opacity:0;" checked="checked" />
```

and this javascript

```
var chosen = '';
len = document.quote_form.q_engine.length;

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
   if (document.quote_form.q_engine[i].checked) {
        chosen = document.quote_form.q_engine[i].value
   }
}
```

For some reason it will not validate. I have the radio element selected but when submit (and alert var chosen it is empty.

I have another form with multiple radio buttons w/ labels. If a label is clicked, the radio is selected and validation works.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Tried to format this post correctly...the var chosen = '' and len=... are both on separate lines

Comment: `document.quote_form.q_engine` is probably not what you’re expecting, e. g., not an object with a `length` property.

Comment: Define “validate”. Include the relevant markup (which should include at least a submit button) and the JavaScript code that actually executes the snippets now included. You should try to present a self-contained document that actually produces the problem, and clearly say what the problem is. “Will not validate” is not a problem description.

Comment: You've set `opacity=0` in your inline style for the radio button. are you using some kind of custom image on top of the default radio button? if yes, it might be possible that your choosing of the image on top of the radio button isnt targeting the default radio button properly.

Comment: a colleague of mine told me to use opacity=0 to solve an IE issue. We did not want the radio buttons to show and positioning them absolutely off the page was not working whereas opacity=0 did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As single radio button doesn't have length property so you need add the condition to make it work,

```
<html><body>

<form name="quote_form">
<!--Radio 1 : <input type="radio" id="20577090" name="q_engine" value="20577090" />-->
Radio 2 : <input type="radio" id="20577091" name="q_engine" value="20577091" checked="checked" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var chosen = '';

if (document.quote_form.q_engine.checked) {
    chosen = document.quote_form.q_engine.value
}
else {
    len = document.quote_form.q_engine.length;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (document.quote_form.q_engine[i].checked) {
            chosen = document.quote_form.q_engine[i].value
        }
    }
}
alert(chosen);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The above code will work whether you have one radio button or more than one radio buttons!

You can read more on this here - http://www.falsepositives.com/index.php/2007/10/16/javascript-for-a-single-element-radio-button-list/

Answer (score 0):

This worked in Google Chrome with the same code:

```
<html>
  <head>
</head>
<body>

<form name="quote_form">
<input type="radio" id="20577090" name="q_engine" value="20577090" style="position: absolute; opacity:0;" />
<input type="radio" id="20577091" name="q_engine" value="20577091" style="position: absolute; opacity:0;" checked="checked" />
</form>

<script>
var chosen = '';
len = document.quote_form.q_engine.length;

var chosen = '';
len = document.quote_form.q_engine.length;

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
   if (document.quote_form.q_engine[i].checked) {
        chosen = document.quote_form.q_engine[i].value
   }
}
alert(chosen);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Script is placed after form.

Comment: jacouh, thank you. If you remove the first radio button in your example you will see my problem, it is alerting an empty value whereas it should alert the value of the checked radio button.

Comment: I thought I was not loosing my mind. For some reason if there is but one radio element it will not work. I guess I could insert a bogus radio button to get it to work though.

Comment: using console.log() instead of alert(): with single radio:

document.quote_form.q_engine.value=20577091
len=undefined

Comment: I am a bit of an amateur and not quite able to interpret that last comment, but I assume that the console is acknowledging that with but 1 radio button it will not work as scripted. I added a "dummy" radio button to my page and it works. The issue I am dealing with is upon loading if there is but one choice I want it hidden and selected, else to show a selection of radio elements requiring one be chosen. Thanks again.